# Does a graph need to be continuous at a point to have a local extremum at said point?

Tags: calculus

Say for example we have a composite function with this graph.

and we take the shown interval $[a,b]$ , can we say that this graph has a local minimum at the point $x=c$?

[image: Example image]

Comment: No, it is an infimum.

Comment: No, it has  a *local maximum* at $c$ – but it is not  a maximum on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: an infimum???

Comment: Oh so what you (Bernard) are saying is that since all points near x=c have a lower value than f(c) then it counts as a *local maximum* ? I can kinda understand that

Comment: An infimum? I don't think I've studied that yet, can you give me a short explanation on what it is?

Comment: You can read about the [supremum and infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) and their relationship with maximum and minimum elements on this Wikipedia page.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Okay, thanks. I'll give it a read

Comment: The *infimum* also has a more descriptive name the **greatest lower bound** and the *supremum* is also called, more descriptively, the **least upper bound**.

Comment: By the way, you can make great graphs easily using the free GeoGebra app. Here is a link to the diagram above: https://ggbm.at/ZUnjuqFd

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales okay thanks, i'll check it out. And I can kinda understand the term "greatest lower bound" but I don't think I really understand the "least upper bound" one. Edit : never mind figured it out

Comment: Let $S$ denote the set of all real numbers **smaller than** $2$. Then the number $5$ is an upper bound on $S$ since no number in $S$ is bigger than $5$. But so is the number $4$ and the number $3$ and the number $21/10$, etc. But the **least** upper bound on $S$ is the number $2$.

Comment: Or in other words, we can say its the *smallest* upper bound ?